# How to Reduce Delay in Displaying Incorrect Password message on Domain PC

Tags: group-policy, domain, authentication, password

I've been encountering an issue with domain PCs where it takes a longer time to notify entering of incorrect password. After conducting some research, we identified that the delay is caused due to system checking the local PC password cache first and then proceeding to check the domain.

Can anyone help me to reduce the time it takes for a domain PC to report an incorrect password message. Any insights or solutions using any methods like GPO etc would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: How much time does it take?  What is the latency between the client and the local DC? What is the latency between the local DC and the PDC emulator role DC?

Comment: **I've been encountering an issue with domain PCs where it takes a longer time to notify entering of incorrect password.** - How much time? 3 seconds to me might be an eternity to you.